# The probability of getting at least 5 balls of the same color from a uniformly distributed set of size 126 with red, blue and white balls

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

I am trying to calculate the following problem:

- I have a uniformly distributed set consisting of red, blue and white balls. This set contains a total of 126 balls, thus there are 42 (${126 \over 3}$) balls of each color.
- I will draw 7 balls.

What is the probability of me getting at least 5 balls of the same color?

What I'm trying to do is:

Calculate the odds of me drawing 5, 6 and 7 of each ball color and then adding them together. Something like this:

$$ P(5 \geqslant \text{Same colored balls}) = P(5 \geqslant \text{Red balls}) + P(5 \geqslant \text{Blue balls}) + P(5 \geqslant \text{White balls}) \\
 P(5 \geqslant \text{Red balls}) = P(5\text{ Red balls}) + P(6 \text { Red balls}) + P(7 \text{ Red balls}) \\
 P(X \text{ Red balls}) = \binom{7}{X} * {1 \over 42}^X * {41 \over 42}^{7-X} \\
 P(X \geqslant \text{ Red balls}) = \sum_{Y=X}^{7} \binom{7}{Y} * {1 \over 42}^Y * {41 \over 42}^{7-Y} $$

Calculating this gives me:

$$ P(5 \geqslant \text{Red balls}) = \sum_{Y=5}^{7} \binom{7}{Y} * {1 \over 42}^Y * {41 \over 42}^{7-Y} \approx 1.5 * 10^{-7} \\
 P(5 \geqslant \text{Red balls}) + P(5 \geqslant \text{Blue balls}) + P(5 \geqslant \text{White balls}) \approx 4.5 * 10^{-7} $$

Is this correct? My probability is a bit rusty.

My actual problem relates to calculating probability in to many hash collision using open addressing if someone is interested in that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I interpret the problem as saying we are drawing *without replacement*. Imagine all the balls have ID numbers.

There are $\binom{126}{7}$ equally likely ways to draw a "hand" of $7$ balls. How many have $5$ red? The reds can be chosen in $\binom{42}{5}$ ways, and the other $2$ in $\binom{84}{2}$ ways, for a total of $\binom{42}{5}\binom{84}{2}$. We have similar expressions for the probability of $6$ red, $7$ red. So the probability of $5$ or more red is
$$\frac{\binom{42}{5}\binom{84}{2}+\binom{42}{6}\binom{84}{1}+\binom{42}{7}\binom{84}{0}}{\binom{126}{7}}.$$

For the probability of $5$ or more of the same colour, multiply by $3$.

**Remark:** If we are drawing *with replacement*, then for example the probability of $5$ red is $\binom{7}{5}(42/126)^5(84/126)^2$, with similar expressions for the probability of $6$ red, $7$ red.

Since $7$ is quite a bit smaller than $42$, the answer we get by assuming replacement  is quite close to the answer we get by assuming no replacement. And if we had for example $900$ balls, and drew $7$, then the probabilities with replacement and without are for all practical purposes the same.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it's without replacement. Should I update the question or let it be?

Comment: The reasonable interpretation of the wording is sampling without replacement.  I put in a remark about with replacement for two reasons. (1) The formula you came up with has a sampling with replacement shape, but with the wrong probabilities $1/42$, $41/42$. (2)  Even in the without replacement case, the sampling with replacement model can sometimes be used to find an approximation that is easier to work with.

Comment: I have a follow up question.
I cannot understand what I get P > 1 when I calculate getting 3 or more from the same color. I think I should use the following formula: 
$ {\sum_{r=3}^{7} {42 \choose r} {84 \choose 7-r} \over {126 \choose 7}} * 3 \approx 1.28799 $
I'm confused by the result. Is the probability 128% that I would get at least 3 of the same color?

Comment: @TomasVestelind:  The expression is not right. For if we draw $7$ balls, it is possible to have, for example, simultaneously $3$ or more red and $3$ or more blue. When you multiply by $3$ you are double-counting these situations. In this kind of situation, you would in general use Inclusion/Exclusion. But here there is a much simpler solution. Look at the complementary event, getting $2$ or fewer of each colour. That would account for at most $6$ balls. But we drew $7$. So $2$ or fewer of each colour is **impossible**, probability $0$. The probability of $3$ or more "matches" is $1$.

Comment: Thank you. 
I choose a bad example here and it's quite obvious now that you pointed it out :)
I wanted to choose an example that illustrates the problem I'm having with my real world problem which would in the case of balls be the same as the probability of getting more than 3 of the same color when drawing 64 balls from 2^32 balls with 128 different colors uniformly distributed. I end up with 178% probability. Is it complicated to avoid double counting in the formula we have for the balls example?
Thank you again for all your help!

Comment: (i) Are there exactly $2^{32}/128$ balls of each colour, or are colours independently assigned at random to each ball, with probability $1/128$? For practical purposes that makes no difference. (ii) One avoids double-counting by using Inclusion/Exclusion. It is a messy formula, but the first few terms will give a good approximation, which may be all you need. (iii) I suggest posting the question with the real numbers involved, describing what you have tried, and perhaps referring to this question. I will be away for several hours, and expect that by the time I get back you will have answers.

Comment: @AndréNicolas You may be interested to note, the OP posted the problem with the exact numbers [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1301023/calculating-the-probability-of-getting-a-full-bucket-in-a-hash-table-with-open-a/1301118#1301118).  If you wanted to double check my answer or provide additional feedback to the OP or me, I'm sure it would be appreciated by both.